# Bluemix availability monitoring - Availability reporting when application is down

Tags: ibm-cloud, availability-monitoring

It looks like, if I pushed a new version of application, there is application downtime and availability is < 100%.

How does the availability computed if I have a planned downtime? If I stopped the application for pushing a new version of application, the availability computation should not be affected.

Alternatively is there any way, I can disable availability monitoring during planned downtime, so that computation of availability monitoring is not affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by stopping the test(s) related to the application during the maintenance window.  However, you may wish to start using blue/green deployments.
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/23610/zero-downtime-blue-green-deployments-using-ibm-devops-services-and-bluemix.html

As long as you don't delete the previous app, your tests will remain.

Availability Monitoring is working on a more natural way to support blue/green deployments (2 apps, 1 set of tests)

Comment: Thanks Adam. This answers.